# Select all rows by variable in WHERE clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

I have a procedure and sometimes I want to select rows with myBool = 0, sometimes with 1 and sometimes all the rows (so nevermind is it 0 or 1). How can I write an expression that does it but using local variable in WHERE clause? So to be constructed like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myBool = @myBool;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way would be to allow `@myBool` to take on `NULL` value:

```
WHERE myBool = @myBool OR @myBool IS NULL
```

I should note that this doesn't optimize well.  But, if you have just two values, then an index is probably not going to be used anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want both then don't need to pass `1 or 0` make it null :

```
where (myBool = @myBool or @myBool is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the simplicity, I would suggest using the values `1`, `0` and `NULL` for `@MyBool`, then you can do the below:

```
SELECT {Columns}
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE MyBool = @MyBool
   OR @MyBool IS NULL;
```

Note, however, that *can* result in some bad query plan caching, so I would recommend adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query.